# TreeMap isn't sorted by my comparator

Tags: java, collections

I have a row of buttons some of them are visible some not. So I want to sort these buttons in order they were added to a panel starting with visible ones.

So I created LinkedHashMap where I add buttons with true if it is visible and false otherwise. Then I created my comparator that sorts this Map by values (Boolean) and only after it I add my buttons to a panel from a TreeMap. But TreeMap is empty at the end.

Here is what I do:

```
private Map<Widget, Boolean> panelButtons = new HashMap<Widget, Boolean>();
private Map<Widget, Boolean> panelSortedButtons = new TreeMap<Widget, Boolean>(comparator);
private ButtonsComparator comparator = new ButtonsComparator(panelButtons);

//UI initialization: buttons are added using addToPanel() method - described below

for(Widget widget : panelSortedButtons.keySet()) { //panelSortedButtons is empty
    panel.add(widget);
}

//----------------

//All buttons are added via this method
public void addToPanel(Widget widget, boolean isVisible) {
    panelButtons.put(widget, isVisible);
}

//----------------

private class ButtonsComparator implements Comparator<Widget>{
    Map<Widget, Boolean> buttons;

    public ButtonsComparator(Map<Widget, Boolean> buttons) {
        this.buttons = buttons;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Widget widget1, Widget widget2) {
        return buttons.get(widget1).compareTo(buttons.get(widget2));
    }
}
```

What is missed if anything?

**Updated**

I understood my fault, I had to fill my TreeMap with data from HashMap. The same way as John B. showed.

```
panelSortedButtons.putAll(panelButtons);
```

Comment: Your question title is misleading, a hashmap doesn't sort anything.  Also, you haven't shown any code where you populate your treemap...

Comment: I miss the compareTo() for Widget

Comment: I think most of the relevant code is missing from what is posted. A "What is missing if anything?" question is best answered from an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: By wich attribute you want to sort? Currently you sort by Widget

Comment: Sorry guys, edited topic. Hope it is more informative now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you return 0 you say that two keys are equal. As Maps don't allow duplicates, returning 0 results in that duplicate being dropped.  In your case you only have two options `true` and `false` so you will never have more than two keys.

However, you say the collection is "empty" which suggests it's not your comparator but you are not adding anything to the collection.

What it appear you want to do is

```
List<Widget> widgets = new ArrayList<Widget>(panelButtons.keySet());
Collections.sort(widget, comparator);
```

You can add the elements, with duplicates to a list like this, and then sort them without losing elements even if they are the "same"

Comment: Yes, you're right, I didn't add my HashMap to TreeMap. One should hit my fingers for this.
At the end I came to your variant because of just 2 records for true and false. As folks say: "Live and learn" :)

Comment: @Dragon I am sure if you stepped through your code in a debugger you would have seen your mistake as you can see what each line of code is doing (or not doing) ;)

Answer (score 2):

You never added the `Widgets` to the `TreeMap`. You created an empty `TreeMap` with a `Comparator` but I don't see where you added any elements to that map.

EDIT:

Try this

```
//UI initialization
panelSortedButtons.putAll(panelButtons);

for(Widget widget : panelSortedButtons.keySet()) { //panelSortedButtons is empty
  panel.add(widget);
}
```

Comment: Edited sample. Btw, in debug mode I see that my HashMode is full of buttons.

Comment: again, I see that you added element to the `panelButtons` map but never added the element so the `panelSortedButtons` map. Where in your code do you do `panelSortedButtons.put(...)`? By passing the `panelButtons` to the `Comparator` you just give the `Comparator` access, you have not given them to the `TreeMap`

Comment: Oh. I thought these two maps would synchronize. I think I have to read more about collections and comparators.

Comment: Yup. The `Comparator` is given each element that is passed to the enclosing `TreeMap` for evaluation. It does not give any elements to the map.

Comment: Yeah, I did the same way as you wrote, then I saw your answer... I seems I started to understand comparators :-[

Answer (score 1):

The method `compare` will never be used in the above code. Also when you implement `Comparable` you should override the method `compareTo` instead of just `compare`.

Also I never see you actually add anything to the collection you have.

Comment: The question is confusing. He is using a TreeMap, but the comparator is using a HashMap.  I think the problem is that his collection is empty because he didn't add anything to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the constructor `TreeMap(Comparator<? super K> comparator)`, previously having defined the `Comparator`.  You are setting the comparator before even declaring it.  This cannot compile.